# Is this set Zariski dense?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator{\proj}{\mathbb{P}}$ This question is related to a [previous one of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3548033/748775). Let $\proj^n=\proj(\mathbb{C}^{n+1})$, and for each $v \in \proj^n$, let $U_v \subseteq \proj^m$ be an open dense subset. Is the set
\begin{align}
\bigcup_{v \in \proj^n} \{v\}\times U_v
\end{align}
Zariski dense in $\proj^n \times \proj^m$?  If this is true, does the statement hold when the $U_v$ are merely Zariski dense? What about if we replace $\proj^n$ and $\proj^m$ with arbitrary quasiprojective varieties?

It was [shown by Alan Muniz](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3548903/748775) that this set is not necessarily *open* dense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. It suffices to prove that it intersects every nonempty open subset nontrivially. But it is clear that any open set in $\Bbb P^n \times \Bbb P^m$ must intersect $\{v\}\times \Bbb P^m$ in a nonempty open subset for some $v$, and then as $\Bbb P^m$ is irreducible, every two open of $\Bbb P^m$ subsets intersect, so we have a nontrivial intersection.

All we needed for this to work is that $U_v$ are open subsets of an irreducible space - so the same setup of $\bigcup_{u\in X} \{v\}\times U_v \subset X\times Y$ with $Y$ irreducible (and no further assumptions) will work. In fact, we could relax our requirement to $U_v$ dense in $Y$ with no other conditions on $Y$ and still get the result.